Confusions regarding battery capacity?
I am reading book Renewable and Efficient Electric Power Systems by Gilbert and in chapter 9 I came across the below attached table, i am confused how last two right most columns values are calculated.
For example, row 1, concorde PVX 5040T, if I use it for 495 A it will last for 20 hours and if I use it for 580 A, it will last for 100 hours? Is my understanding correct?


If you discharge it at C/N, then by definition it will last N hours.
At C/20 it will have capacity of 495 Ah, so will last 20 hours at 24.75 A.
At C/100, it will last 100 hours at 5.8 amps, for a C of 580 Ah.
The difference between those capacity figures is basically expressing the guidance that if you are gentle with your battery, it will deliver more energy than if you thrash it.
There is little point in getting too accurate with capacity figures as a) the capacity drops with age, b) you will get different figures depending on exactly what end-point you take (typically in the 10.5 V to 11.5 V range, which affects cycle lifetime), and c) most people recommend  you use batteries to only 50% discharge to maximise cycle lifetime.

Here in our case, can we know what is value of C?

@DSP_CS C is one of those awkwardly non-constant constants in engineering, like transistor beta that varies slightly with the conditions, but usually by less than a 2:1 range while other parameters vary by orders of magnitude. If you discharge in 100 hours, C will be higher than for a 20 or 10 hour discharge. For discharge times > 10 hours, the C will vary only a little, while the discharge time and currents vary by a lot. C for this battery is 'about 500' Ah. Study the table for details of exactly what's promised at what rate.

C is a measure of current relative to a given battery. It is equal to the nominal Ah of the battery divided by 1 hour. So, if a battery has a nominal capacity of 4000 mAh, C would be 4000 mA of current.
C/20 or C/100 would be just 1/20 or 1/100 of C.  Continuing with our example, for a 4000 mAh battery, C/20 would be 200 mA.  C/100 would be 40 mA.
The last two columns in the table give the expected actual charge available to a user of the battery when it is discharged at a rate of C/20 or C/100. A battery will generally discharge less total charge if it is discharged with higher current than with lower.

Here in our case, can we know what is value of C?

Sometimes things are written to make the reader's task easier but have the opposite effect. From the data sheet relating to the Concord PVX5040T battery the charge is 504Ah, based on this I have made some examples:


